# How to get the second largest Time for a certain Foreign Key in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

For example if I have

[image]

I want to return the second largest time for each "FkID".

In this case it have to return the values with ID = 1, 2, 3, 4, 20, 23, 26,
with the associated time.

Here is some sample data:

```
ID  FkID    Time
1   1       13:22.9
2   2       14:44.8
3   3       15:43.4
4   4       16:31.0
19  11      06:20.6
20  11      06:28.6
21  11      06:36.3    
22  12      02:34.9
23  12      02:39.5
24  12      02:44.3
25  13      22:47.2   
26  13      22:56.3
27  13      23:01.8
28  14      13:03.3
```

Comment: 57:44.9 is not a valid date of time format. What data types are you using?

Comment: @JodyT Thanks, it's fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
 select max(date) 
    from table_name t1
   where date < (select max(date) from table_name where FkID= t1.FkID)
group by FkID
```

Comment: Even though you've fixed part of the problem from your previous effort, you're still trying to find a row where it's `date` value is **greater** than the maximum date value for any related row.

Comment: it looks promising , but it returns nothing

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thanks for your guidance. Am i correct now

Answer (score 0):

Give `ROW_NUMBER` with `CTE`.

**Query**

```
;with cte as 
(
    select rn = row_number() over
    (
        partition by fkid
        order by [Date] desc
    ), *
    from your_table_name
)
select fkid, min([Date]) as [Date]
from cte
where rn < 3
group by fkid;
```

Comment: Change it to where rn = 2

Comment: @sagi : If we change it to `rn = 2`, then the `FKid` which having only one row it will not come.

Comment: @Ullas will it work even if there is a section whereby the FkId has the id 20 repeated 10 times ?